# Mongoose must have a solution for only updating fields that have a value, even if you pass more fields

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a real brain teaser... well for me.

I have a collection where all the documents have the same fields, but may not all contain values for each.

For example:

```
doc1{
    twitter: '*********',
    facebook: '*********',
    linkedin: '*********'
}

doc2{
    twitter: '*********'
}

doc3{
    facebook: '*********',
    linkedin: '*********'
}
```

My challenge is that I want to do an 'updateMany' function where I may pass something like this:

```
updateMany(){
    twitter: '########',
    facebook: '########',
    linkedin: '########'
}
```

and I only want to update the fields in the docs that already have a value and not update all the fields so each document ends up having a value for each field.

So it would look like this:

```
doc1{
    twitter: '########',
    facebook: '########',
    linkedin: '########'
}

doc2{
    twitter: '########'
}

doc3{
    facebook: '########',
    linkedin: '########'
}
```

I'm not sure how to do this without iterating through each record and each field, which seems overly complex.

Mongoose must have something for this scenario...???

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with [$exists](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/index.html) operator but you can't merge all those updates into one database call since different documents will be affected depending on properties (this is because you specify filtering condition and update definition separately), however you can build that query dynamically in JS:

```
let newDoc = {
    twitter: '########',
    facebook: '########',
    linkedin: '########'
};

Object.keys(newDoc).forEach(async (key) => {
    await Model.updateMany({ [key]: { $exists: true} }, { $set: { [key]: newDoc[key] } });
});
```